# Sitecore workbox "Approve all" configure security

Tags: sitecore

In my Sitecore workbox admin can perform "Approve", "Reject" actions from workbox.
By default workbox displays "Approve All", "Reject All" buttons.
Is there a way to control access to these "All" buttons for certain roles by configuring security?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no easy way, because these ***all*** buttons are rendered always together with ***selected*** buttons. The only way I know is to override class that renderes these buttons.

You need to find `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Workbox\Workbox.xml` file and change base class in this line to your own class:

```xml
<CodeBeside Type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm,Sitecore.Client"/>
```

I created one, that always hides ***all*** buttons:

```cs
public class WorkboxForm : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm
{
    protected override void DisplayState(global::Sitecore.Workflows.IWorkflow workflow, global::Sitecore.Workflows.WorkflowState state, global::Sitecore.Data.DataUri[] items, System.Web.UI.Control control, int offset, int pageSize)
    {
        base.DisplayState(workflow, state, items, control, offset, pageSize);

        if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            var borderControls = control.Controls[control.Controls.Count - 1].Controls;
            for (var i = 0; i < borderControls.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 1)
                {
                    borderControls[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

= REST OF THE ANSWER TELLS HOW TO MANAGE ACCESS TO WORKFLOW STATE BUTTONS =

You can define access to these buttons in **Security Editor**.

First login to **Sitecore Desktop** as an *admin*, go to **Start->Security tools->Security editor**. Select role and click **Columns** button:

[image]

Make sure this checkboxes are checked:

[image]

Then in **Security Editor** go to `/sitecore/system/workflows` and configure access rights for your workflow:

[image]

According to  [Workflow Reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Workflow%20Reference.aspx):

> 3.4 **Workflow and Security**
>
> Sitecore defines three workflow specific access rights.
>
> - **Workflow State Delete** — controls whether or not a user can delete items which are currently associated with a specific workflow state
> - **Workflow State Write** — controls whether or not a user can update items which are currently associated with a specific workflow state.
> - **Workflow Command Execute** — controls whether or not a user is shown specific workflow commands.

Comment: I believe this provides authors with access to the items in workflow, but does not disable the Approve All while still allowing Approve?